# Does HL7 messages need start block and end block symbols?

Tags: vb.net, hl7

I am a newbie with HL7 messages.I have to make interface integration between two softwares.I need to send HL7 messages to another software which is developed by other teams.I implement wcfservice to send the HL7 messages.Our software use this wcfservice to send messages.When I test with my own listener testing project,it works.But,when I send to them,they can't receive my messages.They said that I need to put start block and end block symbol in messages.So,I want to clear whether HL7 messages need start and end block symbols or not.

Comment: did you do any research on this yourself before posing, if so can you edit the question with some links to your research. This will give us a better understanding of what / where you are with your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and so sorry for my incompleteness.

Answer (score 2):

Many HL7 *"conversations"* use the **Minimal Lower Layer Protocol** (MLLP) when exchanging messages. Although not a must, it is recommend to stick to it in order to be compatible with other systems without long negotiations.

```
<hex 0x0B>your HL7 Message<hex 0x1C><hex 0x0D>
```

[HL7 MLLP](http://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public_temp_19A0B0DC-1C23-BA17-0CEBE0E3D29DB74D/wg/inm/mllp_transport_specification.PDF)

Comment: So,it means that we need to add start block and end block to HL7 messages,right.

Comment: Yes, if you can not convince the other team to use a an other and better protocol.

Comment: It's good practice upvoting and / or acepting helpful answers g

Comment: I already add start block and end block to my message but when i try to send message to mirth , i got transformer error.please help me

Comment: Yo do not provide enough information for your questions. How does your message look like? Have you validated your message e.g with an external tool http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=HL7_message_validation_tools